# Cannot Android Xamarin Forms UITest to click on DisplayAlert button

Tags: android, xamarin, uitest

I'm using Xamarin UITest to perform UI unit tests. I cannot figure out how to get the UITest framework to click on the DisplayAlert(...) buttons.

```
// this query finds the YES button on the Alert
app.WaitForElement( c => c.Marked( "YES" ).Parent().Class( "AlertDialogLayout" ), "ERR", TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 1 ) );
// but tap with the same query doesn't click it
app.Tap( c => c.Marked( "YES" ).Parent().Class( "AlertDialogLayout" ) );
```

Comment: You can refer to this thread about Handling Pop-ups with Xamarin.UITest https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90847/handling-pop-ups-with-xamarin-uitest

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I did and I don't see how the OK on the pop-up is clicked in your link. My question is specifically about the query that finds the OK button but will not Tap or Click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, at least to me, app.Tap() doesn't require nor accept a query to find either popup button that app.WaitForElement() does. The following works:

```
// this query finds the YES button on the Alert
app.WaitForElement( c => c.Marked( "YES" ).Parent().Class( "AlertDialogLayout" ), "ERR", TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 1 ) );
// but tap with the same query doesn't click it
// but "YES" does!
app.Tap( "YES" );
```

Comment: I had to add `app.Repl();` to my test to see the DOM tree, which showed my "Yes" button was actually named "button1" before this worked. And yes, I'm also using `DisplayAlert` to display the popup question. I'm guessing I'm using a different version or package that implements `DisplayAlert` than this Answer.